# How to import/export Radio Station list of Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

Is it any way to import/export Radio Station list of Rhythmbox?

If not, could you please suggest me any good music player which has similar functionality like Rhythmbox?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean radio stations?

Comment: Yes, I mean radio stations

Answer (score 7):

rhythmbox stores information about all music-files in ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml

Entries concerning radiostations start with "entry type iradio".

Comment: Yeah you are right, I knew that before. But I am looking for some easier way, if one exists.

Answer (score 3):

here's a python script to do the same thing, i.e. extract names and locations of internet radio stations from the xml data base used by Rhythmbox:

```py
import xml.sax.handler
import xml.sax
import pprint

class RhythmboxPlaylistHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inRTitle = False
        self.inRLocation = False
        self.entrytype = "undefined"
        self.titlebuffer = ""
        self.locationbuffer = ""
        self.radiostations = {}

    def startElement(self, name, attributes):
        if name == "entry":
            self.entrytype = attributes["type"]  # we're interested in type="iradio"
        elif name == "title" and self.entrytype == "iradio":
            self.inRTitle = True
        elif name == "location" and self.entrytype == "iradio":
            self.inRLocation = True

    def characters(self, data):
        if self.inRTitle:
            self.titlebuffer += data
        elif self.inRLocation:
            self.locationbuffer += data

    def endElement(self, name):
        if name == "title":
            self.inRTitle = False
        elif name == "location":
            self.inRLocation = False
        elif name == "entry" and self.entrytype == "iradio":
            self.radiostations[self.titlebuffer] = self.locationbuffer
            self.titlebuffer=""
            self.locationbuffer=""

parser = xml.sax.make_parser(  )
handler = RhythmboxPlaylistHandler(  )
parser.setContentHandler(handler)
parser.parse("work_copy_of_rhythmdb.xml")
pprint.pprint(handler.radiostations)

rstations=handler.radiostations

rskeys=[key for key in rstations]
rskeys.sort()

ofile=open("rhytmbox_current_internet_radiostations.txt","w")
ofile.write("#   {0:41}  -->  {1}\r\n".format('radio station name','location'))
ofile.write("#"+120*'-'+"\r\n")
for key in rskeys:
    ofile.write("{0:45}  -->  {1}\r\n".format(key,rstations[key]))
ofile.close()
```

(I started with this tutorial on working with XML data bases from within python: http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonxml/chapter/ch01.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use xmlstarlet to pull the essential data out of your XML file.  See here for details:

http://steffen67.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-export-rhythmbox-radio-stations.html

Comment: nice pointing to xmlstarlet tutorial for this

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I just edited it to include the main idea.  (Thanks for the link.  I was worried that reposting other info would be duplicating web data unnecessarily.)

Answer (score 0):

for exporting read the file  `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml` 

if you  want to import *Create* a **M3U file playlist** as:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,Quran - Eman City  Quran & Islam Talk
http://206.72.199.180:9990/;stream.nsv

#EXTINF:-1,Quran - Radio Quraan
http://66.45.232.131:9994/;stream.nsv

#EXTINF:-1,Quran - Allahu Akbar Radio
http://66.45.232.1ls32:10196/;stream.nsv

#EXTINF:-1,Quran - izlam
http://66.45.232.133:9998/;stream.nsv

#EXTINF:-1,Quran - tafsir Al Sheikh Mohammad Ratib Al Nabulsi & Sheikh Muhammad Mitwalli Al Sharawi
http://206.72.199.179:9992/;stream.nsv

#EXTINF:-1,Quran - radioislamico
http://66.45.232.134:9996/;stream.nsv
```

and open it with rhythmbox