# cannot export radio stations as a playlist

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, playlists

I have installed the [playlist export plugin](https://github.com/petko10/rhythmbox-plugin-playlists-import-export) from the ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins but I can not import or export lists.

I configured the folder where I want to export the lists from add-ons but then I look at the folder and the list of stations does not appear any playlist or radio stations appear in the folder. Any ideas?

I have configured the plugin to export the list of stations that I added to the player but this does not perform the function.

I followed the following instructions for the installation of the plugins

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-complete
```

Comment: https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/installing-rhythmbox-3-0-plugins-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The export playlist plugin only deals with Tracks (Songs) - it is used to save to a file all Tracks in a manually created Playlist that you have created.

The plugin does not export radio-stations.

We do have another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21571/how-to-import-export-radio-station-list-of-rhythmbox) here on AU about how to export radiostations. The output from the script described in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/105601/14356) will need to be modified slightly to create a .m3u format playlist if that is what you are after.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, appreciate your response, I have been very useful @fossfreedom